# How to display username on Facebook fan page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-page

I've googled everywhere for this and I can't figure this out, so any help is much appreciated.

I have an iframe Facebook fan page and want the username to show up with some text.
This is the code I have:

```
<?
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '...',
  'secret' => '...',
  'cookie' => true
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
?>

<? echo $user['name']; ?>
```

It only echoes "0"

I've been trying to do this with the php sdk, but if theres a way to do it with javascript that's fine too.

Comment: have you tried var_dump($user) to see what it contains?

Answer (score 2):

`$user` in your sample code is a string containing user id from Facebook.

You probably wanted to print `$user_profile['name']`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like:

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

And then you'll have:

```
$user['name'];
```

Comment: For the sake of humanity don't do this. Your `$user` variable can be string/array/boolean/null and this is a mess!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$user= $facebook->getUser();  
$fbme  =   $facebook->api('/me');  
echo "Welcome".$fbme['name']."";
```

You can also use

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();   
$fbme= $facebook->api('/'.$uid);
```

where uid will be id for the app user.

Comment: when I use the code in the first example you gave me I get this error Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /homepages/19/d165824150/htdocs/therstyle.com/facebook/milano/src/base_facebook.php on line 1039                                                 Any idea what that means? This is the URL I'm working from http://therstyle.com/facebook/milano/test.php